# How to precompile large text in QTextEdit to avoid freezes on widget first screen appearance

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyside6

I have `QTextEdit` widget, located in a `QTabWidget` tab with `index 1`. I set html file with this code.

```
    def set_help_text_edit_html(self):
        f = QFile("app/resources/help_tab.html")
        f.open(QFile.ReadOnly | QFile.Text)
        stream = QTextStream(f)
        self.ui.help_textEdit.setHtml(stream.readAll())
        f.close()
```

This function is called in `Main Window` `__init__` method, after loading UI class, before calling `show()` for `Main_Window`.

Program starts with tab with `index 0`. So, when i switch tabs to tab with `index 1` (which contains `QTextWidget`), all this html is going to be drawn in real time and that causes lags.
How can i avoid freezes, while loading text document?

Comment: I assume that the contents of the HTML are quite big/complex. QTextEdit lays out the document using the current size, and it doesn't lay out the document again until required (when it's been resized while being visible). What is probably happening is that when the UI is initialized, the QTextEdit has its default size, and the document is laid out for that size, requiring a further layout when it becomes visible. Unfortunately, I don't see ways to optimize or work around this: the layout must happen in the main thread, and it is blocking; even considering the possibility of activating the »

Comment: » main layout upon startup and before loading the html (thus, forcing the QTextDocument to layout its contents with the proper size), the problem would present in any case whenever the window is resized, not only when the widget is visible, but also after being shown (switching to another page, resizing the window, switching back again). You could only consider some sort of "loader" widget (to tell the user that something is happening) superimposed on the viewport and force its displaying before a resize event is processed, but I doubt it would really change things. Consider QWebEngineView.

Comment: @musicamante, thank you for such a detailed response!

Comment: There's no way for doing that without parsing the HTML file manually, extracting HTML fragments, and appending fragments sequentially.